# Issue with visibility :hidden In jquery slidedown() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I am using `display:none` to a div and using `slidedown` function of JQuery to slide the div then it works but the divs get scattered on display:none ,instead of this when i am `Visibilty:none` to a div then the other divs do not scatter but the JQuery does not works.

```css
#slider {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.form-notice {
    display:none;
    float:left;
    width:24.3%;
}
```

Comment: please provide fiddle

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An immediate solution can be:
First Add **margin-left** to your slider class

```
 .slider {
     float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 47.3%;
    margin-left: 329px;
    }
```

And set it **auto** inside this function:

```
$("#request").click(function(){
      $(".form-notice").slideDown();
      $(".slider").css("margin-left","auto");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

`display: none;` takes the element out of the flow of the document, so it does not retain any block level positioning on the page. `visibility: hidden;` simply makes the element invisible, but it still takes up the same space on the page. The built-in `.slideDown()` method (along with `.slideUp()` and `.slideToggle()` ) make use of `display:none`.

Instead, try using the `.animate()` method on the opacity css property and maybe chain a `.css()` method to it that gives it `visibility: hidden;` as a backup for older browsers.

Comment: may i add this method to jquery .firstly i set method to hide on load and chain it with slideup()

Comment: `.slideUp()` will cause the matched element to have `display: none;`, so that will remove it from the document flow. If you don't want this to happen, try this: 

    $('button').eq(0).click(function() {
        $('p').slideUp();
    });
    
    $('button').eq(1).click(function() {
        $('p').animate({'opacity': 0});
    });

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zweb/)

Answer (score 0):

the difference between `display:none` and `visibility:none` is that the `display:none` not fill the place where you placed a div but `visibility:none` occupy the place, and `slide` property add a `display:none` and `display:block` to the element after `animation` is complete. So its better to use `display` property instead of `visibility`.

Comment: but my problem is with div. the other divs get scattered thats the problem.

Comment: so you have to use animation instead of slide to use visibility.

Comment: and also you can use podition absolute to the div which you want to slide. this does not affect the another divs.

Comment: Try doing this: `$('p').animate({'opacity': 0});`. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zweb/)